# LaTex Error: Can only be used in preamble

Tags: compiling

I have been asked to make some edits on a book that was written in LaTex. 
When I compile the main page, it compiles correctly up to one of the chapters, but then I get the following error

```
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 \documentclass
                  {book}
?
```

I'm not super familiar with LaTex, so I am not sure what other information I should be providing in order to explain the problem fully. 
The book was written using /documentclass{article}.
Any ideas or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Probably there is a dangling  `\usepackage{...}`  after the part `\begin{document}`. The easiest to debug such things is to add `\end{document}` just after the `\begin{document}` and slowly change its position down until you hit the error. That marks the first problematic point if there are many.

Comment: Are you inputting a standalone graphic?

Comment: Thanks so much for the input! I found that the problem is in one of the chapters of the book, but I still trying to find out why that chapter is a problem.  I do not think I am using a standalone graphic.

Comment: I just found the problem in the chapter! Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is due to a stray \documentclass in an \input file

Comment: @percusse I was experiencing the same issue. Thanks so much for your suggestion.. so simple, but somehow I couldn't come up with this myself. Thanks!